# Move Bitcoin from account '' to default account

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc, balance

I am running Bitcoind and Bitcoin-cli for my RPC. When I run

`./bitcoin-cli getbalance`

it does not return my correct balance, but when I run

`./bitcoin-cli getbalance ''`

I can see all my funds.

**Question**

How can I move my bitcoin internally, such that I only need to call

`./bitcoin-cli getbalance` to see my balance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected behaviour Bitcoin RPC getbalance](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91831/unexpected-behaviour-bitcoin-rpc-getbalance)

Comment: It turned out that my issue was I was on an old fork of the blockchain